# How to check if the "id" is null or empty then default values are 0 or empty string?

Tags: c#, linq

I write a code using LINQ in C#. The code is working properly but when I try a testing I got no value as in no data and I know if the id is null or empty it will skip the LINQ query. How can I set the value of the query result into a zero or empty string if the LINQ query was skipped?

```
var  Rs1 = _context.DwPropertyDetails.Where(x => x.LandId == id && x.TransactionPrice != null)
                    .Select(x => new
                    {
                        Studio = x.FlatType.ToLower() == studio.ToLower() ? x.TransactionPrice : 0,
                        OneBedroom = x.FlatType.ToLower() == onebedroom.ToLower() ? x.TransactionPrice : 0,
                        TwoBedroom = x.FlatType.ToLower() == twobedroom.ToLower() ? x.TransactionPrice : 0,
                        ThreeBedroom = x.FlatType.ToLower() == threebedroom.ToLower() ? x.TransactionPrice : 0,
                        Total = x.TransactionPrice
                    }).Select(a => new
                    {
                        a.Studio,
                        a.OneBedroom,
                        a.TwoBedroom,
                        a.ThreeBedroom,
                        a.Total,
                        Dummy = "x"
                    }).GroupBy(a => new { a.Dummy })
                    .Select(g => new
                    {
                        Rs1Clm2 = totalTransAmount,
                        Rs1Clm3 = g.Sum(p => p.Studio),
                        Rs1Clm4 = g.Sum(p => p.OneBedroom),
                        Rs1Clm5 = g.Sum(p => p.TwoBedroom),
                        Rs1Clm6 = g.Sum(p => p.ThreeBedroom),
                        Rs1Clm7 = g.Sum(p => p.Total),
                    });
```

well I try it in the View

```
<tbody>
            @if (Model == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Rs1Vms.ToString()) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.Rs1Vms.ToString()))
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>Total Transaction Amount</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var a in Model.Rs1Vms)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => a.Rs1Vm2)</td>
                        <td>@($"{a.Rs1Vm3:N0}")</td>
                        <td>@($"{a.Rs1Vm4:N0}")</td>
                        <td>@($"{a.Rs1Vm5:N0}")</td>
                        <td>@($"{a.Rs1Vm6:N0}")</td>
                        <td>@($"{a.Rs1Vm7:N0}")</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **DefaultIfEmpty** for this task.

```
var Rs2 = Rs1.DefaultIfEmpty(new
                    {
                        Rs1Clm2 = 0,
                        Rs1Clm3 = 0,
                        Rs1Clm4 = 0,
                        Rs1Clm5 = 0,
                        Rs1Clm6 = 0,
                        Rs1Clm7 = 0,
                    });
```

Comment: I try this before. But how about in the view?